# Regex to get Google+ profile ID

Tags: regex, google-plus

i'd wish to extract the ID from a Google+ profile url.
anybody knows if there is a specific pattern?

so far I saw that the profile link is something like this:
`https://plus.google.com/u/0/108137335473606046188/posts`

so I write down this regex:
`#/0/|[^\d]#`

It's working fine, but I'm pretty upset if big G will change the pattern...
Anybody has some more information?

Comment: I voted to close because the possibility of some company changing its URLs is unpredictable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution based on onther facebook regexp and based on Dariusz solution:

```
((http|https):\/\/)?(www[.])?plus\.google\.com\/.?\/?.?\/?([0-9]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use:

```
/\w/\w/|[^\d]
```

which would eliminate the possibility of /u/0/ messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

The `/u/0` portion is not necessarily part of the URL. It is part of the multi-login support for Google accounts and may be completely absent for some users, or may be some other number if they use G+ on a different login session.

Answer (score 0):

This expression can omit problem with additional parameters:

`/plus\.google\.com\/.?\/?.?\/?([0-9]*)/i`

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution on Google+ profile ID:

```
'/plus\.google\.com\/.?\/?.?\/?([0-9]*)/i'
```

The whole example:

```
if (preg_match('/plus\.google\.com\/.?\/?.?\/?([0-9]*)/i', $sUrl, $aMath)) {
    $iGooglePlusId = $aMath[1];
}
```